# Python Pandas - findall() not returning all columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have the following data in my DataFrame

[image]

I want to create another DataFrame by applying one of the filter ( Get all data which belongs to current month ).
To achieve this I am using the following code :

```
search = '2021-07'
month_dataframe=all_dataframe["date"].str.findall(str(search))
```

I think the filter is running properly , because when I print `month_dataframe`, I can see the data, but it is only returning `date` column data, I want all of the columns/data from `all_dataframe`.

Comment: Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if you need a boolean series.

Comment: `df[df['Date'].str.contains(search)]`

Comment: What is the type of your date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input df**

```
    Name    date    address
0   A   2021-07-03  X
1   B   2021-07-03  Y
2   C   2021-07-03  Z
3   D   2021-08-01  M
4   E   2021-08-01  N
5   F   2021-08-01  O
```

**If date col is object/string type and we want to keep it as is**

```
search = '2021-07'
month_dataframe = df[df["date"].str.contains(str(search))]
month_dataframe
```

**If date col is object/str type and we are okay with converting it to datetime**

Benefit in this case is we don't need to define variable `search = '2021-07'` and this solution will work for every(current) month.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
month_dataframe =  df[df.date.dt.month == pd.Timestamp('today').month]
month_dataframe
```

**If date col is datetime type**

(Just an option, not the best way)

```
search = '2021-07'
month_dataframe = df[df["date"].astype(str).str.contains(str(search))]
month_dataframe
```

**Output**

```
    Name    date    address
0   A   2021-07-03  X
1   B   2021-07-03  Y
2   C   2021-07-03  Z
```

Comment: Its type is `Object`

Comment: just remove `.astype(str)` from filter. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the column data type and use filter option.